# PLW-07202: bind type would result in conversion away from column type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write my first PL/SQL Stored procedure in 15 years. I am getting a type conversion warning:

```
2 PLW-07202: bind type would result in conversion away from column type SQL1.sql 11 60
```

when trying to assign the current system time to the following column:

```
CRET_TIMESTMP TIMESTAMP(6)      NOT NULL
```

Here's the whole table definition, for the record.

```
CREATE TABLE FIN_IT_RPT.COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT
    (
        JOB_NM        VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL
       ,JOB_STAT_CD   VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)  NOT NULL
       ,CRET_TIMESTMP TIMESTAMP(6)      NOT NULL
       ,CRET_OPER_ID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL
       ,UPDT_TIMESTMP TIMESTAMP(6)
       ,UPDT_USR_ID   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
    )
    TABLESPACE USERS
    STORAGE (INITIAL 64 K
             NEXT 1 M
             MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED)
    LOGGING;
```

Here's my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIN_IT_RPT.UPDATE_FINODS_COGNOS_STATUS
    (
     P_JOB_STAT_CD IN COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT.JOB_NM % TYPE
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

        UPDATE COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT
            SET
                COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT.JOB_STAT_CD   = P_JOB_STAT_CD
               ,COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT.UPDT_TIMESTMP = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(6))
            WHERE
                COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT.JOB_NM = 'FINODS';

        COMMIT;

    END UPDATE_FINODS_COGNOS_STATUS;
```

Why am I getting the warning and how do I prevent the type conversion? I know it's only a warning, but shouldn't I be able to explicitly convert it to the target type or use a function that natively gets the time in the appropriate format?

Here is what I am using:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.3.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Comment: is it right type for this parameter `P_JOB_STAT_CD IN COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT.JOB_NM % TYPE`? I guess it should be `COGNOS_RPTNG_SCHEDLNG_STAT.JOB_STAT_CD% TYPE`

Comment: oops. But still the warning is on the assignment of the TIMESTAMP column. I made your suggested change and the warning persists. Thank you!

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, your column has `TIMESTAMP` type, may be here is a problem

Comment: I updated my question to try this: CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(6)). Same issue.

Comment: try `LOCALTIMESTAMP` without cast

Comment: I got the same warning. thanks.

Comment: I [created an SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fa88f/3), converted the procedure to an anonymous block, and found that when executed no errors were produced.

Comment: BTW - what happens if you use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, with and/or without the cast?

Comment: Also, try `CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMSTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE)`.

Comment: @BobJarvis - it is only a warning so it won't appear by default, [but you can see it in a Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73be8/1). Same warning with `SYSTIMESTAMP` with and without cast, and casting `WITH TIME ZONE`, and `LOCALTIMESTAMP`, FWIW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, with no fix or real workaround. If you have access to My Oracle Support, look up doc ID 445136.1.

[This forum thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1115765) suggests a workaround:

> Run this block before CREATING or REPLACING your packages, functions, or procedures that exhibit this issue:
>
> ```
> BEGIN
> DBMS_WARNING.SET_WARNING_SETTING_STRING('ENABLE:ALL', 'SESSION');
> DBMS_WARNING.ADD_WARNING_SETTING_NUM(warning_number => 7202, warning_value => 'DISABLE', scope => 'SESSION');
> END;
> /
> ```

Or you can use [the `ALTER SESSION` syntax described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/errors.htm#LNPLS00711):

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS = 'ENABLE:ALL,DISABLE:07202';
```

[This SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73be8/1) shows the warning; [this one with the PLW-07202 suppressed with `DBMS_WARNING`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f00e0e/1), and [this one suppressing with `ALTER SESSION`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a892/1), do not. So that approach works, but of course also suppresses any legitimate warnings of that type.

Comment: I have used an alternative `alter session set plsql_warnings` syntax. If I got the documentation ([PL/SQL Error Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/errors.htm)) right it's functionally is equivalent to `DBMS_WARNING`-package. However the package seems to provide convenience methods to query the current warning settings and thus can be used in source code files to temporary modify warning settings.

Comment: @user272735 - yes, I used the package version because that what was in the forum post; I've added another Fiddle showing that you can do it with `ALTER SESSION` too. As the doc you linked to shows, of course.